# The "content" component has been registered but not used

Tags: vue.js

here is my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <top />
        <content />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import content from './components/content.vue'
    import top from './components/top.vue'
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: { top, content }
    }
</script>

<style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

The lint keeps forming me that

> The "content" component has been registered but not used.

However, I actually use it.
Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Just guessing here but the reason might be that `<content>` is indeed a HTML tag (although a [deprecated one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content)). I'd suggest to give your component a different name or change it to PascalCase (`<Content>`)

Comment: Avoid using a single lowercase word for your components.

Comment: ohh, thanks so much, that works!